# Hibernate criteria JOIN + additional condition (with clause) don't work with many-to-many association

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to add additional condition to Join clause using hibernate criteria. In fact, there are some methods, that allow this to do:

```
createCriteria(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType, Criterion withClause)
```

and

```
createAlias(String associationPath, String alias, int joinType, Criterion withClause)
```

They work properly with one-to-one and one-to-many relations. But when I'm trying to use them with entities having many-to-many relations, I'm getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.
```

Can anybody help me?
The rude example is below:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@ManyToMany
private Set<PersonName> names;

}

public class PersonName {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column
private String name;

}
public class PersonDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {

public List<Person> findByName() {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Person.class, "p");
    criteria.createCriteria("p.names", "names", JoinType.INNER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("name", "John"));
    return criteria.list();
}
}
```

the Query being generated is

```
select this_.id as y0_ from person this_ 
    inner join debtor_info this_1_ on this_.id=this_1_.id 
    left outer join person_person_name personname3_ on this_.id=personname3_.person_id and ( name1_.name=? ) 
    left outer join person_name name1_ on personname3_.person_name_id=name1_.id and ( name1_.name=? )
```

As you can see, join condition is being added two times, what is obviously  incorrect

Thanks in advance.

BTW I'm using postgresql 9, Hibernate 3.6.3

Comment: It seems like a Hibernate bug. Do you want an inner join or a left join. Because if you want an inner join, the with clause could be transformed into a where clause.

Comment: I've set left join manually, but it really doesn't matter what kind of join I use, the error reproduces.

Comment: I have created a defect in hibernate Jira. Let's see what will they day https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7355

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Does somebody know how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug [HHH-7355
Hibernate criteria JOIN + additional condition (with clause) don't work with many-to-many association](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7355) and it will not be fixed because Hibernate Criteria API is deprecated and you should use JPA Crtiterias.
You can try to use HQL [`with` clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

```
from Cat as cat
left join cat.kittens as kitten
    with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```